# Google Sheets - Read only column that i can copy as well

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that I gave editor permissions for a few people that can edit the data.
inside this sheet, I have a column (column B, WEEKDAY) that I want to display as a read-only value according to the value from another column (column A, holding a date value) of the same row.
for example if value of column A is Feb 14th, 2022 then automatically I see value of "Monday" on column B.
in order to prevent mistakes by my editors, I set column B as read-only using the protected range feature.
but, my problem - once I set this protection, they can't copy the entire row to another row, or delete the entire row, as column B is protected.
What is the correct way to solve my need?
using Apps script is possible as well for me.
meanwhile, I changed the protected range from error to warning as I don't have a better solution for now.

I am using ARRAYFORMULA in cell B1, but users can ignore it and manually override the value of B7 (as an example) instead of the formula value. if they do such manual override they get an error on B1 "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B7.". this is the reason I was looking to set column B as read-only so users can not manually override the formula value.

Comment: So, you want users to (1) be able to copy and delete the row, (2) not be able to edit the corresponding value in column B? Also, I assume you are using something like `TEXT(A1,"dddd")`?

Comment: Correct, this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- You are using an [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) on `B1` which populates several cells in column B.
- You want users to be able to copy and delete rows.
- You want users to be unable to edit values in column `B` (since that would mess with the `ARRAYFORMULA`).

#### Solution:

Use an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger which does the following every time a user edit a spreadsheet cell:

- Check whether the user has permission to edit column B, using [Session.getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) (the list of users who have permissions is defined in the script itself, and it may well be empty).
- If the user has permission, check whether the edited cell is in the protected range (`B2:B`), using the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).
- If the edited cell is in that range, remove any values in that range, using [Range.clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent).

Regarding the cell `B1`, which contains the formula, I'd protect it conventionally via Sheets editor ([ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cprotect-a-range-or-sheet)).

#### Code sample:

```
const EDITORS = ["your_editor@domain.com"]; // Users who can edit column B
const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; // Change accordingly
const PROTECTED_COL = 2; // Column B
const FIRST_ROW = 2; // Header row is protected conventionally

function onEdit(e) {
  const userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  if (!EDITORS.includes(userEmail)) {
    const range = e.range;
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    if (sheet.getName() === SHEET_NAME && range.getColumn() === PROTECTED_COL && range.getRow() >= FIRST_ROW) {
      sheet.getRange(FIRST_ROW, PROTECTED_COL, sheet.getLastRow()-FIRST_ROW+1).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- Make sure you modify `EDITORS` and `SHEET_NAME` according to your preferences.

Comment: Great, your solution is good for my needs. Thanks for the detailed answer as well. one thing that isn't working for me is the userEmail. i added line to the log and it looks like userEmail is empty all the time. but it isn't very important for me as no one should be able to edit Col B.

Comment: @AndroidExpert You're welcome! Probably security policies don't allow email address to be populated (probably because the different users are not from the same domain) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser. In any case, it's good to know that's not needed.